# Discord.JS Send all Embeds from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, discord.js

multiple embed pushed in array but i need write them in send message without writing specific number Embeds[0], Embeds[1] and more ...

i cant find a way.

```
let Embeds = [];

Embeds.push(new MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle("title")
   .setColor("#3d9e00")
   .setDescription("TEST"));

msg.channel.send({
   embeds: [Embeds[0], Embeds[1]]
});
```

Comment: `{ embeds }` takes an array of embeds, you have an array of embeds. Use `Embeds`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Embeds` as `embeds` value:

```js
msg.channel.send({
   embeds: Embeds
})
```

By doing: `[Embeds[0], Embeds[1]]` you are just coping the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
let embed = new MessageEmbed()
....

let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
....
msg.channel.send({embeds: [embed, embed2]})
```